# how to run php script on local server using tor layer?

Tags: php, linux, command-line, tor

I would like to ask:
how can i run php script which grabs data from remote service using function **file_get_html** from command line on local PC (linux powered) with different IP address?

I would like to use TOR or something like TOR, i tried to find something usable, but without luck.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

try a service like http://dyn.com/ which gives you a URL/IP for your local computer and will keep tracking your computer IP even if it changes. That way you can access your computer from any other device even if you use apps like TOR.

Comment: I checked it, but seems, that is need to install their client on PC and linux is not supported. Is any other service which offer possibility install their soft and if is soft running on local PC is each request (from browser or command line) send through their proxy servers?

Comment: The problem is your computer IP is likely to change every once and then, and most likely you will be residing behind a NAT network which is a single public IP to different private IP so basically the rest of the internet can't identify your computer by IP. if you have static IP then you can configure your router to forward all traffic on a certain port to your computer this way if someone tried your IP he will hit the router and the router will forward the traffic to your computer.

Comment: But if the computer which makes requests is behind the NAT, is possible to see the IP address of the provider and this is bad, I would like to completly change IP address (comming from different country).